# How to handle two api calls in Angular Subsink?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular-material, mat-table

I am making an api call within `angular subsink` as follows:

```
import {SubSink} from 'subsink';
...
...
async clickButton() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.Id.length; i++) {
        const hostId = await this.serviceA.Status(this.hostName[i]);
        this.subs.sink = this.serviceB.createDbEntry(hostId))
            .subscribe(s => {
                if (i === this.Id.length - 1) {
                    this.dialog.close();
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Here `this.Id` is of type `any`

Now I want to make another api call after the successful completion of `this.serviceB.createDbEntry(hostId)`
And, I am doing it by adding another `subs.subsink` as below:

```
import {SubSink} from 'subsink';
...
...
async clickButton() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.Id.length; i++) {
        const hostId = await this.serviceA.Status(this.hostName[i]);
        this.subs.sink = this.serviceB.createDbEntry(hostId))
            .subscribe(s => {
                if (i === this.Id.length - 1) {
                    this.dialog.close();
                }
            });
        this.subs.sink = this.serviceC.runRetry(hostId))
            .subscribe(s => {
                if (i === thisserverId.length - 1) {
                    this.dialog.close();
                }
            });             
    }
}
```

This is closing the dialog box after `this.serviceB.createDbEntry(hostId))` and not calling `this.serviceC.runRetry(hostId))`

Comment: I dont know what is subsink but try to think about converting the subscribe into promise
with .toPromise() and just use async/await

Comment: Checkout the `switchMap` operator of `rxJs`. I can add an answer if you won't find anything about it.

Comment: I am checking `switchMap` but would also like to request you to add an answer to help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With Using Observables**

You can use `forkJoin` and `switchMap` operator of `Rxjs`.

Check [documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) of `forkjoin` and also

Check [documentation](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) of `switchMap`

With using the operators you can rewrite your code like

```
forkJoin(this.hostName.slice(0, this.Id.length).map(hostName => {
  return this.serviceA.Status(hostName).pipe(
    switchMap(hostId => this.serviceB.createDbEntry(hostId).pipe(map((dbEntry) => ({dbEntry, hostId})))),
    switchMap(resp => this.serviceC.runEntry(resp.hostId))
  )
})).subscribe(() => this.dialog.close());
```

**With Using Promises**

```
Promise.all(this.hostName.slice(0, this.Id.length).map(hostName => 
      this.serviceA.Status(hostName)
      .then(hostId => this.serviceB.createDbEntry(hostId).then(() => hostId))
      .then(hostId => this.serviceC.runEntry(hostId))
      )).then(() => this.dialog.close())
```

Comment: I am getting a warning message `Use the version that takes an array of Observables instead`

Comment: `this.Id` is of type `any`. I am getting this message for `forkJoin` `Deprecated symbol used, consult docs for better alternative `deprecated export function forkJoin<any>(     sources: any):`Observable<unknown[]>`

Comment: I am also getting an error `TS2339: Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'Promise  >'.`

Comment: Why you are using `Promises` rather than `Observables` ? You cannot use it with promises.

Comment: I have a dependency on using `Promises`. Can you please update answer to work with `Promises`? Again, I am able to make a successful first api call and need to make sure the other api call works too

Comment: I added an example with using `Promises` @meallhour